# Error trying to image scrape

Tags: ruby, download, mechanize

I'm trying to make a ruby program which will automatically download the most recent Penny-Arcade.  Here's the code I have:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
date_string = Date.today.to_s

page = agent.get('http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/')
puts page

art_link = page.at('div#comicFrame > a > img')['src']

     File.open(date_string, 'wb') do |fo|
     fo.write open(art_link).read
     end
```

And the output I get from running the program is:

```
$ ruby grab_PA.rb
#<Mechanize::Page:0x007f38bc743af0>
grab_PA.rb:12:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://art.penny-arcade.com/photos/i-QpzhbpN/0/1050x10000/i-QpzhbpN-1050x10000.jpg (Errno::ENOENT)
        from grab_PA.rb:12:in `open'
        from grab_PA.rb:12:in `block in <main>'
        from grab_PA.rb:11:in `open'
        from grab_PA.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

But if I copy that exact link and put it into Firefox, it opens up the image.  What's happening here?  The program does write an image file to the program's directory with today's date, but the file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` takes an argument that's a filename, not an URL. If you want to access the URL, you would normally have to do a lot more than simply open a file.

Luckily, Ruby provides a nice [wrapper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) for `Net::HTTP`, called `open-uri`.

Just drop the following line at the top of your program and it should work fine:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the art_link src (something like art_link.attributes['src']).  And than agent.get from the source.

After you'll have only the image at agent.page.  Just save it by agent.page.save ('image_path_and_name').